# Pass multiple query paramters onConnect Websockets

Tags: websocket, wscat

I need to pass multiple query parameters (QP) to WS URL while connecting.

```
wscat -c wss://abcd.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/?a=1&b=1
```

When I try to pass multiple parameters, `wscat` gets exit with exit code `[10] 96027` . However, works perfectly fine when only 1 QP is passed.

I searched multiple SO threads, all are passing 1 QP. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7):

I was in the same boat. The reason is because & means to execute the command. The solution is to add the double quotation mark in the whole wss url, like this -

wscat -c "wss://abcd.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/?a=1&b=1"